# How to change the app bar title in flutter

Tags: flutter, appbar

```
**change the appbar title dynamically**
```

Getting appbar title from the database and then I have to set to appbar. I am new to flutter tried setState as well.

I have tried setState() as but still not working.
how can i change the appbar text based on server response as well as database value

> ```
> import 'dart:async';
>
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
> import 'package:parking_app/data/database_helper.dart'; 
> import'package:parking_app/models/user.dart';
>
> class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {   @override   State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
>     return new HomeScreenState();   } }
>
> class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {   @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     var db = new DatabaseHelper();
>     Future<User> user = db.getUser();
>     String appBarTitle = "eClerx Parking";
>     var appBarTitleText = new Text(appBarTitle);
> ```
>
> > ```
> > if (user != null) {
> >   user.then((val) {
> >     if (val == null) {
> >       return;
> >     }
> >     print(TAG+ "  user data : " + val.emailId);
> >     setState(() {
> >       build(context);
> >       appBarTitle = val.emailId;
> >     });
> >   });
> > }
> > ```
>
> ```
> return new MaterialApp(
>   home: new Scaffold(
>     appBar: new AppBar(
>       title: appBarTitleText,
>       actions: <Widget>[
>         // action button
>         new IconButton(
>           icon: new Icon(Icons.settings_power),
>           onPressed: () {
>             _logout();
>           },
>         ),
>         // action button
>       ],
>     ),
>     body: new Padding(
>       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
>       child: new ChoiceCard(choice: choices[0]),
>     ),
>   ),
> );   } }
> ```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could also split your code, assuming that your database fetch will be asynchronous.

```
class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
     var appBarTitleText = new Text("eClerx Parking");

     Future getUser() async {
        var user = await db.getUser();

        if (user != null) {
           user.then((val) {
              if (val == null) {
                return;
              }
              print("user data : " + val.emailId);

              setState(() {
                appBarTitleText = Text(val.emailId);
             });
           });
        }
    }


    @override
       void initState() {
       super.initState();
       getUser();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't do everything in the build function. The build function is redrawing everytime you call `setState`, so you are initiating `String appBarTitle = "eClerx Parking";` every time it redraws.

You need to override the `initState()` and place this logic in there

```
var db = new DatabaseHelper();
    Future<User> user = db.getUser();
    String appBarTitle = "eClerx Parking";
    var appBarTitleText = new Text(appBarTitle);


if (user != null) {
  user.then((val) {
    if (val == null) {
      return;
    }
    print("user data : " + val.emailId);
    //DO THIS TO UPDATE THE STATE AND FORCE A REDRAW
    setState(() {
      appBarTitle = val.emailId;
    });
  });
```

Also, wrap `appBarTitle = val.emailId;` with setState() function

EDIT: You are not awaiting the result from the dababase `Future<User> user = db.getUser();` so the user will always be null and setState never called.

Try `Future<User> user = await db.getUser();`

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
appBarTitle = val.emailId
```

to

```
setState(() {
  appBarTitle = val.emailId;
});
```

Comment: Hey Günter! I think he is trying to do everything inside the build function, so calling setState there may not work. I tried to answer it down below. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: It's not ideal there but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I mean yes, you are right, it's not ideal but it should work. Maybe the problem is that he is not awaiting the response to the db `Future<User> user = db.getUser();` so the user will be always null and won't call setState, what do you think?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer made changes in my code added setState method still not working and in logs, print method is getting called infinite times

Answer (score 0):

create global variable name it appBar Title inside `statefulwidget` state class

```
var appBarTitle ="some text";
```

and assign appBar title to it

then change its value with `setState` method